# Adding a header and text to UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios6, fonts, uitextview

I thought this would be simple but it's proving not to be.

I have some text that I need to display in my app. What is the best way to present it? Because I want the text but also want a header - the header will be larger. I know `UITextView` only allows 1 type of font/size.

Example of what I want

**Example Header** - Bold size 22

Text - size 16

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your text is not editable, I think you can think about UILabel instead of UITextView, and you can use more complicated view hierarchy, not just an UITextView or UILabel.
If you insist using UITextView, I think you can refer to NSAttributedString.

Comment: Yea it's just a block of text/information I am displaying, i want it to be able to scroll tho. Can this be done using IB or does code need to be used to add text to a view

Comment: How can I do it ? i cant find the answer, i dont have long to get it finished :S

Comment: I was busy these days, sorry for late reply.I recommend you to use UILabels instead of UITextView, you can put these UILabels in a UIScrollView to make scrollable. It seems attributedText is only available in iOS6 for UITextView. Wish helpful to you